# How to install latest CouchDB on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, couchdb

How to install latest CouchDB on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 15.04, 15.10, 16.04, etc?

I spent around an hour trying different ways and instructions for installing latest CouchDB on my Ubuntu 12.4 installation. I have posted the best way that I found as answer to save other peoples time.

Answer (score 7):

Install the latest stable release with the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:couchdb/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
```

<sub>[Source](https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable)</sub>

Comment: I got `couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed` with this method.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Debian Jessie :(.

Comment: before running the apt-add-repository, make sure you have: apt-get install software-properties-common

Comment: Check also this url for a easier installation https://gist.github.com/christophemarois/f63e9ec6e6663c2e7bcaf0ce4f29d55e

Answer (score 2):

Run this script:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir x
cd x

set -e

sudo apt-get update || true
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install build-essential pkg-config runit erlang libicu-dev libmozjs185-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

wget http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/apache/couchdb/source/2.0.0/apache-couchdb-2.0.0.tar.gz

tar -xvzf apache-couchdb-2.0.0.tar.gz
cd apache-couchdb-2.0.0/
./configure && make release

sudo adduser --system \
        --no-create-home \
        --shell /bin/bash \
        --group --gecos \
        "CouchDB Administrator" couchdb

sudo cp -R rel/couchdb /home/couchdb
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /home/couchdb
sudo find /home/couchdb -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
sudo sh -c 'chmod 0644 /home/couchdb/etc/*'

sudo mkdir /var/log/couchdb
sudo chown couchdb:couchdb /var/log/couchdb

sudo mkdir /etc/sv/couchdb
sudo mkdir /etc/sv/couchdb/log

cat > run << EOF

export HOME=/home/couchdb
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -u couchdb /home/couchdb/bin/couchdb
EOF

cat > log_run << EOF

exec svlogd -tt /var/log/couchdb
EOF

sudo mv ./run /etc/sv/couchdb/run
sudo mv ./log_run /etc/sv/couchdb/log/run

sudo chmod u+x /etc/sv/couchdb/run
sudo chmod u+x /etc/sv/couchdb/log/run

sudo ln -s /etc/sv/couchdb/ /etc/service/couchdb

sleep 5
cd /tmp/x/apache-couchdb-2.0.0

sudo sv status couchdb    mv rel/couchdb /usr/local/bin/
cd ..
rm -r /tmp/x



cat <<EOT >> /etc/systemd/system/couchdb.service
[Unit]
Description=Couchdb service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=couchdb
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/couchdb/bin/couchdb -o /dev/stdout -e /dev/stderr
Restart=always
EOT

systemctl  daemon-reload
systemctl  start couchdb.service
systemctl  enable couchdb.service
service couchdb start
```

then open the url http://localhost:5984/_utils/

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest *Source* package of CouchDB from [couchdb.apache.org](http://couchdb.apache.org/#download) and extract it
2. Open INSTALL.Unix or any other appropriate readme or install file
3. RTFM™ and follow instructions, install unmet dependencies if any and Relax!™

Answer (score 0):

While this post is not focused on Ubuntu (but rather debian on a Raspberry Pi), I was successful in following these guidelines on Ubuntu:

http://jeeonthepi.blogspot.de/2014/08/installing-couchdb-1.html

Outline:

1. Add Erlang repositories to your package manager
2. Install Erlang
3. Install spidermonkey
4. Install libicu
5. Install curl
6. Set up user account for CouchDB
7. Download CouchDB source code
8. Do configure/make/make install
9. Create soft links
10. Make CouchDB config writable

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use snap to install CouchDB.Only 2 commands needed.

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install couchdb
```

Source: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004390/8191838)