# How to upgrade to CouchDB 2.0 (or latest) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: couchdb

I'm hoping to upgrade to CouchDB 2.0 (or latest) on my Ubuntu 14.04 (Ubuntu Gnome).

Does Ubuntu itself use the CouchDB install it comes with? And will I be breaking anything by upgrading CouchDB?

How do I actually go about this?

Comment: I see only _version 2.0_ for _MAC and Windows_, see [here](https://couchdb.apache.org/?__utma=172270774.1814816626.1482221823.1482221823.1482221823.1&__utmb=172270774.6.10.1482221823&__utmc=172270774&__utmx=-&__utmz=172270774.1482221823.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=181709287)

Comment: Hmm... source, but no Ubuntu packages. Got it. I'll look into when that might be ready.

Comment: Chck this site for a 2.0 installation https://github.com/apache/couchdb

Comment: I posted a solution in another answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/640288/how-to-install-latest-couchdb-on-ubuntu/909757#909757